# How to filter using NSPredicate based on if the to many relationship set contains a specific value

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate

I have to two entities. One entity `Person`, the other `Message`. For every one Person, there are many messages (so there is a one to many relationship). I need to populate my tableView with Persons, but only Persons which have a set of messages that has at least one message with the attribute `sent` equalling `success`.

If what I said is not clear, here is basically what I want:

(obviously this does not compile, I completely made it up for the sake of the question)   `NSPredicate(Person.messages.contains (sent == "success")`

Edit:
Forgot to mention that I'm using Core - Data, not just a regular array. I need that NSPredicate for fetched results controller.

Comment: What is "friend" in your predicate?

Comment: let me edit that, i meant Person. Sorry

Comment: Something like `NSPredicate(format: "ANY messages.sent == %@", "success")` should work. Did you have a look at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/AdditionalChapters/Introduction.html?

Comment: Thank you very much Martin R ! I could not find the swift version of the docs. Plus your answer looks like it should work !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"ANY" can be used with a to-many relationship to find the
objects for which at least one of the related objects satisfies
a condition. In your case:

```
 NSPredicate(format: "ANY messages.sent == %@", "success")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use filter function on swift array like so:

```
struct Person {

    var name: String?
    var meessages = [Message]()
}


struct Message {

    var sent: Bool = false
}


let arr: [Person] = [
    Person(name: "person1", meessages: [Message(sent: true), Message(sent: false)]),
    Person(name: "person2", meessages: [Message(sent: false), Message(sent: false)]),
    Person(name: "person2", meessages: [Message(sent: true), Message(sent: true)])
]

let filtered = arr.filter({ ($0.meessages.filter({ $0.sent == true })).count > 0 })
```

Comment: ThomasG, thank you very much for your answer, although I need an NSPredicate for core data to use for my fetched results controller, I should have been more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because your Persons Array should be NSArray , NSPredicates works only with Foundation objects not swift types.in Swift arrays
you have filter method that you can call and pass it the filtering closure.